# Route an Istio Virtual Service based off the user claim in a JWT

Tags: kubernetes, jwt, istio

Istio can route traffic based off headers and such.  There are [great examples](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/) of how to do this in the Istio docs.

Istio can also validate your JWT.  The Istio docs also [cover that](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-jwt/).

But I can't seem to find a way to get my JWT Validated, then use the user claim found in the JWT Json to route traffic.  The example I linked to just expects the user to be plain text in a header.

How can an Istio Virtual Service be setup to route based on a claim in a JWT (preferably one it validated).

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this using the **Istio authorization policy**. I did something similar with Keycloak and Kong to restrict user traffic at API gateway level if claim or roles were not there.

[Here](https://github.com/binc75/istio-jwt#inspect-jtw-token) is one nice example of JWT auth with istio:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
 name: backend
 namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: "${KEYCLOAK_URL}/auth/realms/istio"
    jwksUri: "${KEYCLOAK_URL}/auth/realms/istio/protocol/openid-connect/certs"
---
# To allow only requests with a valid token, create an authorization policy
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
 name: backend
 namespace: default
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: backend
 action: ALLOW
 rules:
 - from:
   when:  
    - key: request.auth.claims[preferred_username]
      values: ["testuser"]
```

Example link : https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-jwt/

Another nice example with OIDC : https://www.jetstack.io/blog/istio-oidc

RBAC and group list checks : https://istio.io/v1.4/docs/tasks/security/authorization/rbac-groups/